# Multicol and page break

Tags: multicol

Why "Dirichlet process" is splitted so that page 1 ends with "Dirichlet" and an empty line?

```
\documentclass[b5paper, finnish, 11pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[bottom=0.9in,top=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}

\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount} % Kappaleiden välin asetus
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}          % Kappaleen alun sisennys   (0pt,  ts. ei sisennystä)
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{15pt}  % Helpotetaan tavutusta sallimalla pidemmät sanavälit

\begin{document}

{\raggedright\hyphenpenalty=0

\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}

cumulative sum chart

\vspace{8mm}
\scalebox{2}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont \textbf{D}}
\vspace{2mm}

\textbf{\textit{D}-optimaalisuus} $D$-optimality

\textbf{\textit{d}-separaatio} $d$-separation

\textbf{Dantzig-valitsin} Dantzig selector

\textbf{data} data

\textbf{data-analyysi} data analysis

\textbf{datajoukko} data set

\textbf{datakehikko} data frame

\textbf{datakuutio} data cube

\textbf{datamatriisi} data matrix

\textbf{datan esikäsittely} data pre\-processing

\textbf{datan linkittäminen} data linkage

\textbf{datan ruoppaus} data dredging

\textbf{datan syvyys} data depth

\textbf{datan tiivistäminen} data reduction

\textbf{datan kurkistelu} data peeking

\textbf{datanlouhinta} data mining

\textbf{datan myrkyttäminen} data poisoning

\textbf{datatiede} data science

\textbf{datavetoinen} data driven

\textbf{de facto -väestö} de facto population

\textbf{de jure -väestö} de jure population

\textbf{deflaatio} deflation

\textbf{degeneroitunut jakauma} degenerate distribution

\textbf{dekomponointi} decomposition$_1$

\textbf{dekomponoituva malli} decomposable model

\textbf{dekonvoluutio} deconvolution

\textbf{deltamenetelmä} delta method

\textbf{demografia} demography

\textbf{derivaatta} derivative$_1$

\textbf{derivoituvuus} differentiability

\textbf{desiili} decile

\textbf{determinaatiokerroin} coefficient of determination

\textbf{determinantti} determinant

\textbf{deterministinen} deterministic

\textbf{devianssi} deviance

\textbf{devianssi-informaatiokriteeri} deviance information criterion

\textbf{devianssijäännös} deviance residual

\textbf{diagnostiikka} diagnostics

\textbf{diagnostinen suure} diagnostic sta\-tis\-tic

\textbf{diagnostinen testi} diagnostic test

\textbf{diagonaalimatriisi} diagonal matrix

\textbf{diagrammi} diagram

\textbf{differenssiyhtälö} difference equa\-tion

\textbf{differensointi} differencing

\textbf{differentiaaliyhtälö} differential equa\-tion

\textbf{differentioituvuus} differentiability

\textbf{differointi} differencing

\textbf{diffuusi priori} diffuse prior

\textbf{diffuusioindeksi} diffusion index

\textbf{diffuusioprosessi} diffusion process

\textbf{digammafunktio} digamma function

\textbf{dikotomia} dichotomy

\textbf{dikotominen muuttuja} dichotomous variable, binary variable

\textbf{dimensiokirous} curse of dimensionality

\textbf{dimension pienennys} dimension reduction

\textbf{Diracin deltafunktio} Dirac's delta function

\textbf{Diracin mitta} Dirac measure

\textbf{Dirichlet-jakauma} Dirichlet distribution

\textbf{Dirichlet-prosessi} Dirichlet process

\textbf{diskonttaus} discounting

\textbf{diskordanssi} discordance

\end{multicols}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The setting `\raggedright\hyphenpenalty=0` seems a bit clumsy. If you delete it and execute `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` instead, the odd/unfortunate page break disappears.

Comment: True. Can you make this an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the instruction `\hyphenpenalty=0` is meant to allow hyphenation pretty much everywhere. The instruction `\raggedright` both suppresses full justification *and* discourages line breaking that involves breaking up and hyphenating words. The two directives may be in conflict with each other, leading to the unpleasant page break. (Hyphenation in a LaTeX document is governed by several "penalty" parameters; `\hyphenpenalty` is just one of them.)

What to do? I suggest you delete the two instructions mentioned in the preceding paragraph and, in their stead, run

```
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
```

in the preamble. That way, ragged-right typesetting is in force everywhere in the document -- even in footnotes, should your document contain them -- while hyphenation isn't unduly discouraged. (While you're at it, you should also comment out or delete `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` as it's redundant if the `ragged2e` package is loaded with the `document` option.) Running `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` assures that `\RaggedRight` is active by default for all document elements.

By the way, section 3 of the user guide of the `ragged2e` package contains a very nice explanation of some of the practical shortcomings of LaTeX's implementation of `\raggedright` -- and why it's therefore often preferable to use the package's `\RaggedRight` command instead if full justification is to be avoided.

Here's a screenshot of the bottom of page 1 and the top of page 2 of the resulting test document:

[image]